# Check if a particular user is authenticated

Tags: laravel, authentication, session

Is there any way to check if a particular user is logged-in in a webapp? I have searched and all the results are `Auth::check()` but this isn't what I need. I would need something like `Auth::check($user_id_to_check)`. Don't really known if this is even possible.

This is basically to output an image with a green or red circle in the user avatar of a comment system.

Thanks for any advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

Or

```
$id = Auth::id();
```

[Check The Doc here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check specific id with logged in `user_id` then you can do something like this

```
\auth()->id() == $user_id_to_check
```

`auth()` is helper to get auth user and related information.

For more [Auth Helper](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-auth)

Answer (score 0):

What he is surely trying to do here is to show all users whether a user is online or not. To do this you have to implement other logic. And `Auth::check()` will not work as it only checks that the user who is sending the request is authenticated.

If you remember the last action of user and you know the timeout until a user gets logged out automatically this would give you an estimate value if the user is still logged in or not.

Add a migration for your users table and add a new field to your table

```
$table->timestamp('last_activity')->nullable();
```

You need to do a check somewhere on your application and update this timestamp.

```
if (Auth::check()) {
  Auth::user()->update([last_activity => now()]);
}
```

Now you can check when the last action of user was and if this is within the auto logout time it is possible that the user is still logged in. If not the user is definitely logged out.